# Developer options on Alcatel OneTouch M Pop 5020D?

Tags: android, usb-debugging

I have a quite new Alcatel OneTouch Pop M 5020D. But I am not able to find or activate the developer optione for activating USB debugging. Does anyone know how to?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Go to: Settings > About phone > Tap on Build number few times.
Good luck!

Answer (score 2):

On the Alcatel OneTouch Evolve 5020T (T-Mobile) the USB debugging option was under Settings -> About phone -> Advanced settings.

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

Had the same problem. Did the first tip but there one more thing which needs to be done.
**It needed to be switched on "Media device (MTP)" option in "USB computer connection" menu.** Without this option my mac wasn't seen the device.

Answer (score 0):

You have to install the MTK Driver (http://support1.alcatelonetouch.com/cari/faq/faq-gallery/FaqsPerCategory/72) recording to the instructions of the android plattform for development (http://developer.android.com/tools/extras/oem-usb.html#Drivers) and you have to enable development settings and the usb debugging feature under Settings -> About Phone -> Advanced settings.